# angularjs facebook 500 ok error

Tags: facebook, angularjs

i am using angularjs directive for facebook sharing.

angularjs directive controller, i am loading facebook javascript sdk.
angularjs directive link function, i am showing login and after login, i am showing sharing dialog.

```
       link : function(scope, element, attrs){
              scope.share = function(){
                  FB.ui(
                      {
                          method: 'feed',
                          name: attrs.fbName,
                          caption: attrs.fbCaption,
                          description: attrs.fbDescription,
                          link: $location.absUrl(),
                          picture: 'http://www.fbrell.com/public/f8.jpg'
                      },
                      function(response) {
                          if (response && response.post_id) {
                              alert('Post was published successfully.');
                          } else {
                              alert('Post was not published.');
                          }
                      }
                  )
              }
              element.bind('click', function(){
                  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                      if (response.status === 'connected') {
                          scope.share();
                      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                          alert("user is not authorized ");
                      } else {
                          FB.login(function(response) {
                              if (response.authResponse) {
                                  scope.share();
                              } else {
                                  alert("please login first");
                              }
                          });
                      }
                  });
              });
         }
```

it is working in firefox but in chromium, it is not working.it is giving HTTP 500 ok error.

i have searched a lot on it and find it is server side error.
how to resolve it Or what should i do to resolve it?